# Manually building active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an active record query that is not using an index, resulting in app timeouts.

```
domain.services.where.not(parent_service_id: nil).group('services.type').select('services.type, count(services.id) as user_count')

=> [#<ServiceModel id: nil, type: "ServiceModelName">]
```

I have a custom sql command that forces use of the index on parent_service_id

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT services.type, count(services.id) as user_count FROM services where domain_id = 21227 AND parent_service_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY services.type")

=> {"type"=>"ServiceModelName", "user_count"=>"2810"}
```

Which returns the information I need quickly.  However, it returns a hash instead of a model.  How do I build out an activerecord object so my method can return a similar result?

Comment: Show the SQL from your logs that the first statement produces.

Comment: this my be useful for you [http://m.onkey.org/use-index-with-active-record-finders](http://m.onkey.org/use-index-with-active-record-finders)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `connection.execute`, you should just be able to do:

```
ServiceModel.find_by_sql(sql)
```